# How to build Spark application with custom Spark, i.e. with local changes to its sources?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I usually compile with `sbt package` with my .sbt file containing:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
```

I made some changes to Spark source that I want to test so the above no longer works since it does not see the changes. How can I compile using my local version of Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I made some changes to Spark source
>
> How can I compile using my local version of Spark?

You have to build the locally-modified Spark version and use that version.

Assuming that you downloaded Spark 2.1.0's sources, you should build them as described in [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/building-spark.html).

The command I use to build Spark from the sources is as follows:

```
./build/mvn -Phadoop-2.7,yarn,mesos,hive,hive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean install
```

After you built Spark, you change **nothing** in `build.sbt`, but you have to use that Spark's `spark-submit` your Spark application (that will distribute the proper jars for execution).

Comment: This works as long as I don't introduce new methods e.g. add method `schema2()` in `DataFrameReader`, which is what I want.

Comment: What issue do you face after you've added `schema2`? I'd change the `version` in `build.sbt` / `pom.xml` and build.